# Google Chrome plug in to read saved cookies

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, cookies

I'm new to Google Chrome plug in development. I have learnt how to develop a basic plug in. Now the problem is I'm trying to make a plug in that can read saved cookies of a particular website you visit.

For instance, a user visits www.facebook.com, after login he will click on our plug-in icon and a drop down window will appear and show all the cookies saved by Facebook. 
Here I want to ask how to read the cookies of the site you are visiting? Is that possible to sort cookies with respect to site you visit?

If yes? Can you provide me a reference of how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Cookies API](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/proposal-chrome-extensions-cookies-api) that allows Chrome extensions to access the browser's cookies, without having to send HTTP requests to obtain those cookies. [More references](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html)

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439377/access-cookies-from-google-chrome-extension) might also be helpful.