# Access of third-party extensions to my cookies

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, google-chrome-extension

There are used cookies on my website. Recently I noticed some cases of scamming when a third-party extension steals user’s session cookies and sends it to scammers. 
Is it possible to prohibit access of browser extensions to cookies of my website? With the help of any meta tag maybe?

Comment: An extension can read any cookie you transfer to the browser so the only way to prevent this is to not use cookies or add an additional layer of security (like 2FA is an added layer for user+password).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** `HTTPS` is a must. Extensions have absurd level of access to the `cookies`, including `httponly`. Looking over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439377/access-cookies-from-google-chrome-extension), a `manifest.json` can point to an extension script that ultimately gets access to your cookie, but if you are using `CSP` header to whitelist domains, then I presume the extension cannot do anything with it, unless they work at a lower layer (scripts are injected (:facepalm:) so CSP isn't applicable to them, alas from what I read, it looks like that....)

I would consider first controlling the third party apps that I want to allow communication. For that, consider:

- `Content-Security-Policy` header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

To make use of above, you 'need' to switch your protocol to `https`.

Next, it is still possible that scripts you trust can exhibit malicious behavior, then for those cookies that are strictly private, set those cookies from the server side with `httponly` option:

- `Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly`

This way js cannot access them. Read through the cookies **[@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)**

Needless to say, do not allow other people to get access to your window:

- If you use `oWindow = window.open(.....)`, make sure `oWindow` does not have access back to you: `oWindow.opener = null`;
- If you have links etc, always use `rel='noopener noreferrer'` attribute on them.
- Prevent other windows from opening your page in an iframe: `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

Lastly, I do not recommend this (I didn't try either) as it does not provide real security, however if you are sure the third party implementations do not need XMLHttpRequest, you can monkey patch it, delete it from the global:

```
 XMLHttpRequest  = (function(xhtp){
       //do whatever you need here while you have access
       return null;
    }(XMLHttpRequest))
```

or alternatively remove the `withCredentials` getter/setter from the prototype as this never affects same origin anyway (supposed **not** to):

```
delete XMLHttpRequest.prototype.withCredentials
```

Comment: It won't affect extension's content script (or the background script's using chrome.webRequest API) which can access any page cookies.

Comment: It is true, however extensions are installed at the choice of the client and they have absurd level of access. There is no other solution either. Although, I presume if I know what domains the extension needs to communicate to, then not specifying those domains in the CSP, will ultimately work because yes, the extension will have access to the cookie, but cannot send it anywhere.

Comment: Correct or not?

Comment: Extension's background script can send it anywhere (it depends on its manifest.json) regardless of your page CSP.

Comment: I wrote it pre-edit just now. So there is no other solution than advising your users to only use 'trusted' extensions from the web store. Is that it?

Comment: People who install malware extensions are usually don't even know what an extension is so I don't think they'll understand the advice. As for a solution, I would try to find some differences in the request log on the server.

Comment: So ultimately we cannot do anything about the extension grabbing the cookie. However what is done with that cookie later on from another domain (REMOTE_ADDR, REMOTE_HOST etc) is where we can intercept (maybe), is that what you are saying?