# Chromeextension that uses browser Cookies to make reqeuests

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, google-chrome-extension, python-requests

Is it possible to make a Chromeextension, that can take Cookies from your browser, to use them for a post/get request?

Comment: [Learning about how Chrome extensions can access cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/) and [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) would be a great place to start.

Comment: There is a pattern you can use from this post...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439377/access-cookies-from-google-chrome-extension

Comment: Thanks to you Guys! Will read trough that tommorow. Good night ;)